# installing libcppunit in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

I am tryig to install the cppunit library in ubuntu 12.04, and I don't know how!!
I have tried with:

$ sudo apt-get install cppunit

and I get an error saying that there is no install candidate, the same messenge I got when I tried:

$ sudo apt-get install libcppunit.

I tried downloading the source but it did not work at all (instruction unclear)
what can I do??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
```

There's a `libcppunit-doc` too, and a `libcppunit-1.12-1` - could be that you need that instead?

I looked up packages for Ubuntu 12.04 with `cppunit` in the name at http://packages.ubuntu.com/:

[Ubuntu Packages - Search "cppunit" for Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=cppunit)